# i want to show data from indexedDB to the view, im using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexeddb

i want to retrieve data from indexdedDB using Reactjs, but i couldnt figure how to return it to view,

this is my code........

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';



function Mypokemon() {
    var db;
    var request = window.indexedDB.open("pokemon_data", 1);
    //on error opening DB
    request.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log("error: ");
    };

    //on success opening DB
    request.onsuccess = function (event) {
        db = request.result;
        console.log("connected to DB")

        db.transaction(['data'], 'readwrite').objectStore('data').openCursor().onsuccess = function (event) {
            var cursor = event.target.result
            if (cursor) {
                //something to do here for applying data to html
            };


        }
    }
    //this code below for make the empty table
    request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
        var db = event.target.result;
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("data", {
            keyPath: "id"
        });
        console.log('success make table')
    }

    return (<div className="flexin" id="my_poke">
        {/* this where the data should showning */}
    </div >)

}
export default Mypokemon;
```

can someone help me, om sorry my code structure :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

E.g.:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Mypokemon() {
    const [ value, setValue ] = useState();

    useEffect(function(){
        const valueFromDb = getValueFromDb();  // make your request
        setValue( valueFromDb );
    },[]);

    return (<div className="flexin" id="my_poke">
        { value }
    </div >)

}
export default Mypokemon;
```

Comment: i tried this but whenever i tried to console.log(value) after it got setValue, it return nothing.... and its only when i reload the page.